# What does "the sum of every third element in the $n$-th row of Pascal's triangle" mean?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, combinations, problem-solving

I am looking at the following problem. I don't want to know how it's done,  I would just like to see the problem reworded in less confusing terms if possible:

[image]

Comment: Remembering that the $n$'th row, $r$'th diagonal entry (*treating first row as row $0$ and first diagonal as diagonal $0$*) is $\binom{n}{r}$ it is asking you to investigate the nature of $S_{n,0}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{3k}$ as well as $S_{n,1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{3k+1}$ and $S_{n,2}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{3k+2}$.  (*you could decrease the upper bound on the summations but I'm lazy to figure out exactly how to write it with floors and ceilings, the excess unnecessary terms are zero anyways so it doesn't matter*)

Comment: It doesn't say "calculate $S_{100,1}$". Looking at how the values have been highlighted, you could simply conjecture that $S_{100,1}=S_{100,0}$ and $S_{100,1}=S_{100,2}-1$

Comment: It should be mentioned that supposing that conjecture were correct, you can find the value by remembering how the sum of *all* entries on a row of pascals triangle relates to the powers of two.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks a lot

Comment: Further to @JMoravitz point about the row total, my previous statement would then turn into $S_{100,1} = (2^{100}-1)/3$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$S_{n,0}$ is the sum of every third element in row $n$ of Pascal's triangle, starting with the first element in that row.  So, for example, $S_{5,0}$ is the sum of every third element in row 5 of Pascal's triangle, starting with the first element in row 5.  Then we get $S_{5,0} = 1 + 10 = 11$.  The elements we're using in row 5 are in red below: $$ \color{red}{1} \quad 5 \quad 10 \quad \color{red}{10} \quad 5 \quad 1 $$

$S_{n,1}$ is the sum of every third element in row $n$ of Pascal's triangle, starting with the second element in that row.  So, for example, $S_{5,1}$ is the sum of every third element in row 5 of Pascal's triangle, starting with the second element in row 5.  Then we get $S_{5,1} = 5 + 5 = 10$.  The elements we're using in row 5 are in red below: $$ 1 \quad \color{red}{5} \quad 10 \quad 10 \quad \color{red}{5} \quad 1 $$

$S_{n,2}$ is the sum of every third element in row $n$ of Pascal's triangle, starting with the third element in that row.  So, for example, $S_{5,2}$ is the sum of every third element in row 5 of Pascal's triangle, starting with the third element in row 5.  Then we get $S_{5,2} = 10 + 1 = 11$.  The elements we're using in row 5 are in red below: $$ 1 \quad 5 \quad \color{red}{10} \quad 10 \quad 5 \quad \color{red}{1} $$

Make a conjecture about the value of $S_{100,1}$.  That is, see if you can determine a pattern that will allow you to calculate the value of $S_{100,1}$, which is the sum of every third element in row $100$ of Pascal's triangle, starting with the 2nd element in that row.

Answer (score 3):

Let ${n\choose k}$ be the $k^{th}$ entry of the $n^{th}$ row of the triangle.  (starting at $k=0$)

$S_{n,0} = {n\choose 0}+{n\choose 3}+{n\choose 6}+\cdots\\
S_{n,1} = {n\choose 1}+{n\choose 4}+{n\choose 7}+\cdots\\
S_{n,2} = {n\choose 2}+{n\choose 5}+{n\choose 8}+\cdots$